# How can SublimeRepl connect to remote server and execute my code in that server?

Tags: ssh, remote-access, sublimerepl

I installed SublimeREPL without any problems. Now I would like to use my remote machine as the default interpreter. Is is possible to do so for SublimeREPL? I found [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zodAqBvKQm0) but it uses `venv`. If possible, I prefer plain ssh connection.

Comment: It shows you how to do this in the video.

Comment: if u understand it, pls tell me :)